# Retrieving from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a pre registering system with these tables:

1. StudentInfo
2. Courses
3. Departments
4. SystemAdmin
5. RegisteredCoursesCompletely
6. RegisteredCoursesIncomplete

After creating a login using a stored procedure I need to show the courses that are related to a particular `dep id`. I did it. After that I needed students to be able to choose every course and then add it to a table and this is where the problems began...

I have two kinds of buttons. One of them is `Registered Completely` it means user never can go back and changes the courses (I did it) but the second one is `Registered Incompletely` it means user can go back and see what he/she chose and then uncheck it or check something else.

---> I want to do this in this way if he/she go back I want to show them all courses that related to them with courses that they chose before I mean the checkbox that consisted of data that user checked in the first time. Also show courses that not have been checked yet. All of them in a one grid view.

Please help me. I do everything that my lecture needs but this part that i try to solve it is a little tricky. I used to session and then save the index of the grid view that user checked and then insert it to database but you know more than 20 units user can choose and how do it please explain it with complete code.

Comment: You are not being very clear as to what the question really is. Do you have trouble with the database setup/database design? Do you have trouble with the ASP.NET functionality? Some table structures and/or a screenshot or something might help - right now, I'm just scratching my head and don't know how and if I can help ....

Comment: If this is your final project, then you should have all the tools you need to solve this problem, without someone else solving it for you.  Stop, relax, think it through, draw it out as a diagram or a workflow.  Your description is not very clear (as @marc_s has pointed out), so that makes me think you need to spend more time fleshing out the problem.  Break the problem into manageable chunks, and you can do it.  We've been there, don't panic.

Answer (score 1):

in `Registered Incompletely` scenario you need to save selected courses, user and flag with `Registered Incompletely`. Then any time same user logged in or go back you can load all the courses and mark the selected courses based on previous saved data. if user is `Registered Completely` then you can save `Registered Completely` flag and user details in the database.

Edit:

students and registration complete status need to saved on database, here you can have Boolean value for that. true for complete, false for incomplete. if you have several pages to select courses, then in each page when you move next, save current courses selection in the database. it can be used when you want.

Comment: thanks so much for answering me. 1- What do you mean with flag. 2- Please show me in writing code in asp.net and c#.

Comment: I try it out more than 4 times with every solution that i know but i can't  do it. I need it as soon as possible.